# Why is MS Word continuing a numbered list from the body to the footer

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, page-numbers

When I insert page numbers, a numbered list is being added next to the page number in the footer. The main body on page 2 looks like this:

> 1.1 Text in numbered list
>   1.2 Text in numbered list
>   2.1 Text in numbered list
>   2.2 Text in numbered list

The footer looks like this (the "3." is being added automatically):

> `3. -2-`

It should just look like this:

> `-2-`

I can manually remove the numbered list from the footer, but it reappears every time I use the insert page numbers function.

Comment: The Page Number Format shows "1, 2, 3, ..." The "Include chapter number" box is unchecked.

Comment: @Ken, The insert page function inherits the formatting from the location where the field is inserted. Press Shift+F1 to reveal formatting and click the caret to that paragraph. Is there any auto number formatting associated with that paragraph or any of the others?